# Error with installing textgenrnn

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I`m trying to install library called textgenrnn, followed by this in docs:

```
pip3 install textgenrnn
```

Got error that my Python version is 2.7:

```
Collecting textgenrnn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/69/5d995322502f8a33d408c547a6dbf00e74d4434ecc1b704b684260739b21/textgenrnn-1.3.1.tar.gz
textgenrnn requires Python '>=3' but the running Python is 2.7.15
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I also check my Python version using this command:

```
python -V
```

and get

```
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Update: After uninstalling anaconda I got this:

```
dmitriy@dmitriy-PC:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.15rc1
dmitriy@dmitriy-PC:~$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.5
```

My first think is to delete or disable python 2. But after googling I decided that python2 is impossible to uninstall or disable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making python3 as your default by setting the alias command or you can configure the .bashrc file for conda and set the path for conda

alias python='python3' #create python3 as your default

get install via pip

Another Method:
create a environment after you install conda and you will get a python3 environment. From there you can install via pip

Either of the method should work here.

Answer (score 0):

Just install library from source.

```
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/69/5d995322502f8a33d408c547a6dbf00e74d4434ecc1b704b684260739b21/textgenrnn-1.3.1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf textgenrnn*.tar.gz
cd textgenrnn-1.3.1
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

That`s all!